# Speeding up to writing to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
t0 = time.time()
chars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))
header = ['A', 'B', 'C']
t0 = time.time()
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 10):
        for A in numbers_list:
            pure = str(A) + ':' + str(combination) 
            B = pure.replace(")", "").replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
            B1 = [ord(char) - 96 for char in B.lower()]
            B2 = str(B1)
            B3 = B2.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "") 
            C = hashlib.sha256(B.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            C1 = [ord(char) - 96 for char in C.lower()]
            C2 = str(C1)
            C3 = C2.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "") 
            writer.writerow([A , B3[:10], C3[:10]])
tdelta = time.time() - t0
print(tdelta)
```

I am having an issue with understanding how to speed up writing to CSV file. I am bit new to programing in Python. Is there anyway to speed up the way this script or would it be impossible? I would be really appreciative the help! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried pandas for this task? It should help. Check 'read_csv' fuction

Comment: Good evening Krzysztof Chojnacki, I tried pandas but I kept running into an issue of running out of memory causing my computer to slow down and freeze. I have only been coding for a few months. so I have a lot to learn.

Comment: If you want to speed something up, you first need to know what takes the most time. I would start by simplifying the string operations and by using plain text file instead of `csv`. Pandas is most definitely NOT the way to go.

Comment: Thank you jurez, I will try writing to a text file.

Comment: In read_csv from pandas you have argument 'chunksize' - you can define how many rows should be processed. This will help you with this problem.

Comment: @KrzysztofChojnacki, Pandas will only make this **slower**.

Comment: I just wrote `pure` to a text file, and counted how many lines were written, and got, `wrote 8.2e+07 lines in 54.30s`. Most of the slowness is due to the magnitude of the work you're doing; disk IO will be a major bottleneck. What exactly are you trying to do, big picture? And like @jurez stated, Pandas will only make this **slower**.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools, hashlib, pandas as pd,time, csv
chars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))
rows = []
for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 10):
        for A in numbers_list:
            pure = str(A) + ':' + str(combination) 
            B = pure.replace(")", "").replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
            B1 = [ord(char) - 96 for char in B.lower()]
            B2 = str(B1)
            B3 = B2.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "") 
            C = hashlib.sha256(B.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            C1 = [ord(char) - 96 for char in C.lower()]
            C2 = str(C1)
            C3 = C2.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")
            rows.append([A , B3[:10], C3[:10]])
t0 = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.to_csv('data.csv',chunksize = 10_000, index=False)
tdelta = time.time() - t0
print(tdelta)
```

Krzysztof Chojnacki , something like this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).